# Query to highlight if a row is deleted from table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I need to create a report/alert that advises me if a row of data is removed. The data comes out of a case management system in a fixed format -

```
SELECT 70383 AS field_id
        , 'Demo_field' AS FieldName
        , '2022-12-05 11:41:49.753' AS AuditDateTime
        , 2 rnk
        UNION ALL
SELECT 70383 AS field_id
        , 'Demo_field' AS FieldName
        , '2022-12-04 11:41:49.753' AS AuditDateTime
        , 1 rnk
```

This traces any changes in the field table which is a config table in the system - what happens is that a field (70383) is deleted from the system as it's obsolete, so I need to run a query that tells me this field existed yesterday but is no longer in the data today so i can update the ETL process. I cant do a row count as 1 field could be removed and 1 field added.

I've attempted a few variants using the rnk field and LAG and LEAD but can not seem to get the desired output (a field that advises the column has gone) . Please ask any questions if I haven't been clear

Comment: So do you store details of the deletions you do? If not, how do you know it's deleted, and (more importantly) how would SQL Server?

Comment: @Larnu the row would no longer be in the data - so you would have a row for that field every day up until it's deletion

Comment: So you create a row *every* day? Seems like you could therefore just use a `NOT EXISTS` to compare yesterday's data to today's; if the `field_id` doesn't exist in today's data, it's "gone".

Comment: @Larnu didnt even think of that.... thanks!